# Reverse Polish Notation for Java?

Tags: java, string, stack, int, java.util.scanner

I changed my code to use if-else statement, but I still have a problem.

When I tried to type = in unix, it didn't print out 0. Also it didn't print out anything when I type anything. What's wrong with that..Please help

Sorry I am newbie, please be patient to me.

```
public static void processCommand(String s) {
  //If an "=" is received, print zero always
     if (s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '=') {
         System.out.println(0);

    }
}
public static boolean isOperator(String s) {
    return (s.equals("+") || s.equals("-") || s.equals("*") || s
        .equals("/"))  || s.equals("%");
  }

public static void main(String[] args)  {

String s;
//create a stack called st
Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



while (scan.hasNext())  {
s = scan.next();


    if (isOperator(s)) {
        if (st.size() > 1) {
            if (s.equals("+")) {
            st.push((Integer) st.pop() + (Integer) st.pop());
            } else if (s.equals("-")) {
            st.push(-(Integer) st.pop() + (Integer) st.pop());
            } else if (s.equals("*")) {
            st.push(-(Integer) st.pop() * (Integer) st.pop());
            } else if (s.equals("/")) {
            int x = st.pop();
            int y = st.pop();

            if (x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Cannot be divided by zero");
            } else {
            st.push(y/x);

                    }
                }
            }

     processCommand(s);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Simple: don't use switch...

Comment: if else statement should be ok? I am a newbie so I don't know a lot.

Comment: Why don't you try ? ;)

Comment: Can you formulate a clear question out of your code?

Comment: Sorry I just changed it.. Please help

Comment: You're trying to call `IsOperator(s)`, but you're calling `sIsOperator(s)` which fails. Now where could be a mistake here?

Comment: I know the mistake is there but I don't know how to fix it..:(

Comment: How about removing the first `s` of `sIsOperator`? Or in over words: make sure that the method name in this statement `if (sIsOperator(s))` is correct. And if you never created a method with the name `IsOperator` or `sIsOperator`, then the whole line doesn't make much sense. You cannot call something that isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make  processCommand(s); statement  outside the loop and it will work.